# The return type of a function with a return type of ostream&

Tags: c++

I am wondering what this function would return?

`ostream& Canister::display() const;`

The function definition is:

```
ostream& Canister::display() const{
    
    cout.width(7);
    if (m_usable == false) {
        return
            cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << capacity() << "cc (" << m_height << "x" << m_diameter << ") Canister" << " of Unusable content, discard!";
    }
    else if (m_contentName != nullptr) {
        return
            cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << capacity() << "cc (" << m_height << "x" << m_diameter << ") Canister"
            << " of " <<
            setw(7) << volume() << "cc   " << m_contentName;
    }
    else if (m_usable == true) {
        return
            cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << capacity() << "cc (" << m_height << "x" << m_diameter << ") Canister";
    }
}
```

The code runs perfectly when I compile it on Visual Studio, but when I tried compiling on vim it gave me this error:

```
Canister.cpp: In member function 'std::ostream& sdds::Canister::display() const':
Canister.cpp:176:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: Vim might just have a more naive parser that doesn't realize that at least one of those branches _must_ be true and is worried about the fact that without a trailing `else`, it might be possible to exit the function without returning. EDIT: Assuming `m_usable` is a `bool` and `if(m_usable == false)` is just a verbose way of saying `if(!m_usable)`. If `m_usable` is actually some other type, it may well be possible for Vim's warning to be correct.

Comment: `else if (m_usable == true)` The `if (...)` part is redundant, since you know that `m_usable == true` already. The `else` part is also redundant since the previous `if` will have `return`'d otherwise. So you can remove that entire line, which will make it more clear to the compiler (and future readers) that all code paths return a value.

Comment: Is your question about the warning from vim, or are you seeking to understand what each `return` statment ends up returning? Please clarify, because as it's currently worded, it's not obvious what the focus of the question is about.

Comment: Thanks for everybody who commented! I am trying to get rid of the error message on Vim so I can compile it and submit it for school.

Comment: I fixed it, @NathanPierson 's comment helped. What I did is I added a dangling else with "return cout << "\0"; and it compiled.

Comment: vim is just an editor. What plugin was it that gives the warning? Also, you mention a compiler error. Can you describe the vim setup a little more clearly?

Comment: @cigien, I used g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g -o to compile on Unix and I got the error I included in the original post, my bad you can tell I’m still a newbie.

Comment: No worries. You're using GCC (probably) to compile, not vim. What do you get when you run `g++ --version`?

Comment: Note that you're getting a compiler **warning**, not an **error**. The code does compile even though the compiler complains.

Comment: It's g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Comment: Welcome to the battle of warnings. While **you** know that all paths lead to a return statement, the compiler isn't as smart as you, and it's telling you that it doesn't think you're right. The usual solution, other than turning off the warning, is to add a `return` statement at the end of the function. But then when you change compilers you'll get a warning about unreachable code, pointing at that return statement.

Comment: Re: `return std::cout << '\0';` -- that's more elaborate than needed. `return std::cout;` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for describing the environment clearly. In the future, make sure to add that to the question body when posting.